# Unable to access data from mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I followed a tutorial, connected to mongoDB via mongoose, but for some reason the console.log(data) doesn't show anything.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoURI = 'mongodb+srv://gofood:xxxxxxxxx@cluster0.bgpaa3e.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority'

process.on('uncaughtException', err => {
  console.log('UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION!  Shutting down...');
  console.log(err.name, err.message);
  process.exit(1);
});

async function called(){
  console.log('Connection successful!');
  const fetched_data = await mongoose.connection.db.collection("foodCategory");
  console.log('reaching here?????')
  fetched_data.find({}).toArray(function(err, data){
    if(err) console.log(err);
    else console.log(data);})
};

const mongoDB = async () => {
  await mongoose
    .connect(mongoURI, {
      useNewUrlParser: true
    })
    .then(() => called())
}

module.exports = mongoDB;
```

output:-

```
[nodemon] starting `node .\index.js`
Example app listening on port 5000
Connection successful!
reaching here?????
```

In the tutorial the data comes up instantly. Is there something that I'm not doing?

Comment: code example seems incomplete.  I don't see a connection string in your code.

Comment: In the shown code you don't connect to any database.

Comment: i thought only primary function is needed. here i added the entire file. It connects with db and tries to fetch the given collection.

Comment: one more thing just to check i tried giving incorrect collection name but nothing happens. code next to it i.e "reaching here" still works.

Comment: Still the same. You defined `mongoDB` but you don't use it at any place.

Comment: i have exported mongoDB and then imported it to my index,js where it is called. It is being called successfully as we can see console.log messages are printed

Comment: thanks for your help, i found the prob and was able to fix it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how i fixed it.
I was wondering that in my function i'm providing my collection name but not database name. later i found that in the mongoDB url you have to mention the database name

old url

`const mongoURI = 'mongodb+srv://gofood:xxxxxxxxx@cluster0.bgpaa3e.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority'`

new url

`const mongoURI = 'mongodb+srv://gofood:xxxxxx@cluster0.bgpaa3e.mongodb.net/**gofoodmern**?retryWrites=true&w=majority'`

Answer (score 1):

Try **await** until u find all the data

```js
async function called(){
  console.log('Connection successful!');
  const fetched_data = await mongoose.connection.db.collection("foodCategory");
  console.log('reaching here?????')
  await fetched_data.find({}).toArray(function(err, data){
    if(err) console.log(err);
    else console.log(data);})
};
```

Comment: [] this in console. the thing is even if my collection name is incorrect i'm still getting the same output. what could be wrong here

Comment: thanks for your help, i found the prob and was able to fix it

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the called() function like this:

```
async function called() {
console.log('Connection successful!');
const FoodCategory = mongoose.model('FoodCategory', new mongoose.Schema({}));
const data = await FoodCategory.find().exec();
console.log(data);
}
```

May be it's work!!

Comment: []  now i'm getting this in console for data

Comment: the thing is even if my collection name is incorrect i'm still getting the same output. what could be wrong here

Comment: thanks for your help, i found the prob and was able to fix it